# List field in blackberry

Tags: blackberry

How we give onclick event on list in blackberry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [Field.html navigationClick](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.2.1api/net/rim/device/api/ui/Field.html) method to start handling the click.